# What is this tiny plant with multiple leaves and small white tubercles scattered over its leaves?

Tags: identification, succulents

Could you please help me with identifying the following plant?

It's a tiny one, smaller than a forefinger. It has multiple dark green leaves, with small white tubercles scattered over each leaf. The tubercles are prominent on the lower (outer) side of the leaves, but the upper (inner) side of leaves have less clear tubercles, too.

Here's a picture:

[image: Cactus-like plant]

Comment: At first I thought it looked like an Aloë variety, like Aloe Margaritifera. But after some searching, I think it's the related Haworthia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This plant is [Haworthia attenuata var. radula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haworthia_attenuata) – Hankey Dwarf Aloe or one of it's cultivars. A native of South Africa it is stemless and propagated by removing small offsets that grow out from the base.

This plant looks very similar to [Aloe aristata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloe_aristata) and definitive identification depends on examining a more mature specimen.